# shapes are not visible using force

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to get a simple node graph example working.  My dataset has two nodes and a single link between them.  Everything looks good up to the point where I call force.on(...)  Using a debugger I have stepped through the code watching the link and node coordinates get updated.  Code looks like below.

```
var force = d3.layout.force().charge(-200).linkDistance(30).size([width, height]);

force.on("tick", function () {
                link.attr("x1", function (d) {
                    return d.source.x;
                })
                .attr("y1", function (d) {
                    return d.source.y;
                })
                .attr("x2", function (d) {
                    return d.target.x;
                })
                .attr("y2", function (d) {
                    return d.target.y;
                });

                node.attr("cx", function (d) {
                    return d.x;
                })
                .attr("cy", function (d) {
                    return d.y;
                });
            });
```

Using Chrome Developer tool,  the page source looks like below and it looks ok.  Just can't figure out why its not view-able on the page.

```html
<div id="graph" width="100% height="100%>
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" pointer-events="all">
  <line class="link" x1="409.333616222992" y1="384.486594023154"   
        x2="390.5843732878489" y2="415.65241380113304"></line>
  <circle class="node Person" r="10" cx="409.333616222992" 
          cy="384.486594023154"><title>Peter</title></circle>
  <circle class="node Person" r="10" cx="390.5843732878489" 
          cy="415.65241380113304"><title>Michael</title></circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Check your `<div>`'s `width` and `height` attributes. Both are missing a closing quotation mark.

Comment: The closing quotation marks are OK.  Not sure why they do not appear in my above copy / paste.

Comment: The closing quotation marks are OK.  Not sure why they do not appear in my above copy / paste.  My problem appears to be that the div area is very small, it only takes up about the top 20% of the page.  The svg area is in the div's area.  But, the line and circles are drawn further down below in the page.  They are about where I want them, but getting the parent tag areas larger appears to be the challenge.  I am a bit of an html novice.